# R na.omit - single vs multiple files - list files vs read.csv?

Tags: r

Read 1 file and omit Na's:

```
z <- read.csv(file="C:/data/specdata/002.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",") 
newdata <- na.omit(z)
```

`newdata` works as it should and shows no `NA`s.

Read multiple files in directory:

```
files <- list.files(path = "C:/data/specdata/", pattern='^\\d+.csv')
lst <- lapply(files, read.csv,header=TRUE)
newdata <- na.omit(lst)
```

I get the same results for `lst` and `newdata`, i.e. `NA`s are still present. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you are calling `na.omit(lst)`, na.omit will try and omit missing values from the list `lst`.  I suspect what you want to do is:

```
newdata <- lapply(lst,na.omit)
```

Alternatively, if the data.frames in `lst` all have the same structure, you might want to `rbind()` them togeather before calling `na.omit`, as in:

```
newdata <- na.omit(do.call(rbind,lst))
```

Comment: Your first solution does the job. Yet for second R tells that there was more than 50 errors. And data structure is same for all 300 files

Comment: `read.csv` guesses at the structure of each data frame based on the file it is reading in.  Most likely, read.csv is returning data.frames with slightly different structures.   If you want verify this you can see the classes of each variable in each data.frame by calling `lapply(lst,function(x)lapply(x,class))` .  If (in the future) you want to be assured that all the data.frames have the same structure, you can specify 'colClasses=...' when calling `read.csv`.